# Python to receive huge string as argument from rabbitmq

Tags: python, json, rabbitmq, pickle

On Raspberry 3 I run a Rabbit-Mq listener.py that receives a large string (json) consisting of 14000 key/value pairs. The listener.py script will grab this string and pass it along to another script(database.py) that will encode it back to json(python dict object), parse it and store the values to a Mariadb database.

The listener.py calls:

```
os.system("python %s %s" % (database.py, body))
```

where "body" is the string received from rabbitmq.

I have a concern that the 14000 objects json might be to big to pass to database.py as `sys argument`. Are there any other methods I could achieve my goal? I just heard about pickle, is it better for my purpose?

Comment: Why don't you accept the data in database.py directly?

Comment: @MKesper well listener.py runs in a "While True:" loop and is responsible of sending out different commands to many scripts (database updates, graphs, downloads etc). I need this sort of modular approach to keep my code clean

Comment: @BogdanMirceaStanciu but that doesn't need to go via an `os.system` call. Import database and call methods directly?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to use multiprocessing.connection with its [Listener and Client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing.connection). These methods use pickle internally.

Comment: This seems promising. And one of the reasons I call another python script trough "os.system" is to have multiple python processes running at the same time.

Comment: Sounds like you'd want a Process Pool (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing.pool) then.